# What happens if you receive a heart container when at max hearts?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Beyond the primary method of exchanging 4 Lights of Blessing at a Goddess statue, it seems you can earn heart containers related to the progression of the main story quests (without spoiling where/how, it looks like there are 7 heart containers that are obtainable outside of requesting from Goddess).

With that said, it seems it would be entirely possible to complete enough shrines to fill your hearts to max (40) before finishing some or all of the story mode when these quest reward heart containers would be obtainable. In this case, what happens when you collect this heart? Does the game give you a stamina vessel instead, give you 4 Lights of Blessing instead, or something else?

Comment: In Botw, the heart container would just stay outside the divine beast until you came back and collected it. Something similar may happen in Totk, too. Or you'll get a stamina vessel.
Getting 4 lights of blessing seems unlikely.

Comment: @pinckerman yeah I don't know if it would try to 'compensate' you somehow with giving you a stamina vessel instead or anything, or if it would make you exchange a heart and come back to get this heart container. If the latter, that's a bit of an inconvenience, and a cost to do so.

Comment: I think it just stays sitting there until you have room for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pick up the heart container unless you have room for it, and it will stay at the place where it dropped until you pick it up.

Comment: This does not answer what happens with the heart container when picked up. If you mean that you cannot pick it up while having max hearts, pls add that information.